# How to add pagination in api driven vue app?

Tags: vue.js

I have a get api that looks like this -

```
this.$API +"api/v1/puzzles/getAll?page=" + this.pageNo +"&limit=" + this.pageLimit,
```

It accepts two params **page** and **limit**. How to make pagination for this get api ?

**My html code:**

```
<md-card>
            <md-card-header data-background-color="green">
              <h4 class="title">List of Puzzles</h4>
              <p class="category">The list of puzzles you have uploaded</p>
            </md-card-header>
            <md-card-content class="justify-content-center">
              <table>
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th><b>Puzzle Question</b></th>
                    &nbsp;
                    <th><b>Option 1</b></th>
                    <th><b>Option 2</b></th>
                    <th><b>Option 3</b></th>
                    <th><b>Option 4</b></th>
                    <th><b>Correct Answer</b></th>
                    <th><b>Action</b></th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr v-for="(data, index) in puzzleList.puzzles" :key="index">
                    <td class="q-img"><img :src="data.qImage" alt="" /></td>
                    &nbsp;
                    <td
                      class="ans-img"
                      v-for="(collection, index) in data.qOptions"
                      :key="index"
                    >
                      <img :src="collection.oImage" alt="" />
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding-left: 32px">
                      <h2>{{ data.qAnswer }}</h2>
                    </td>
                    <router-link to="/editPuzzle"
                      ><td style="padding-top: 70px">
                        <button class="btn btn-success">Edit</button>
                      </td></router-link
                    >
                    <td>
                      <button
                        v-on:click="deletePuzzle(data.id)"
                        class="btn btn-danger"
                      >
                        Delete
                      </button>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
                <!-- <pagination v-model="pageNo" :pageLimit="500" @paginate="myCallback"/> -->
              </table>
            </md-card-content>
          </md-card>



data() {
    return {
      siteURL: this.$axios.defaults.siteURL,
      puzzleList: [],
      pageNo: 1,
      pageLimit: 4,
      token: localStorage.getItem("_token"),
      puzzleId: "",
    };
  },
```

I tried to use third-party packages but couldnt make it work. I have taken 2 variables inside return above like **pageNo: 1** and **pageLimit: 4** and haven't found any solution anywhere with this type of api. Please show me detaily, how should I implement this ?

**Update:**

```
<table>
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th><b>Puzzle Question</b></th>
                    &nbsp;
                    <th><b>Option 1</b></th>
                    <th><b>Option 2</b></th>
                    <th><b>Option 3</b></th>
                    <th><b>Option 4</b></th>
                    <th><b>Correct Answer</b></th>
                    <th><b>Action</b></th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr v-for="(data, index) in puzzleList.puzzles" :key="index">
                    <td class="q-img"><img :src="data.qImage" alt="" /></td>
                    &nbsp;
                    <td
                      class="ans-img"
                      v-for="(collection, index) in data.qOptions"
                      :key="index"
                    >
                      <img :src="collection.oImage" alt="" />
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding-left: 32px">
                      <h2>{{ data.qAnswer }}</h2>
                    </td>
                    <router-link to="/editPuzzle"
                      ><td style="padding-top: 70px">
                        <button class="btn btn-success">Edit</button>
                      </td></router-link
                    >
                    <td>
                      <button
                        v-on:click="deletePuzzle(data.id)"
                        class="btn btn-danger"
                      >
                        Delete
                      </button>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <pagination
                    v-model="pageNo"
                    :pageLimit="4"
                    @paginate="myCallback"
                  />
                </tbody>
              </table>

methods:{
myCallback(e) {
      this.pageNo = e;
      this.getPuzzle();
    },
    getPuzzle: function () {
      this.$axios
        .get(
          this.$API +
            "api/v1/puzzles/getAll?page=" +
            this.pageNo +
            "&limit=" +
            this.pageLimit,
          {
            headers: {
              Authorization: "Bearer " + this.token,
            },
          }
        )
        .then((res) => {
          this.puzzleList = res.data.data;
          this.puzzleId = res.data.data.puzzles[0].id;
          console.log(this.puzzleId);
        });
    },
```

Comment: No external libraries used https://github.com/Jebasuthan/vue-pagination. It will helps you to implement pagination in your application

Answer (score 0):

any third-party of pagination api has the property that you should set the current page and the limit or total, the main of pagination is that current page,page size, total and the callback of current page changes, the lifecycle is that:

1. init: you fetch the api with the params(currentpage, pagesize) to get data, then according to your response ,you can get the total count of your data
2. use the 1 step response like total count, and give it to your pagination component
3. don't forget to declare your onChange callback ,which the pagination component necessary to use, in the callback ,you just change the current page which user click and fetch your api again to get the new data.

Comment: I have provided my code above inside "My HTML code". Please help me to implement this. I also added a package in it. But cannot figure out how to implement this using the api.

Comment: witch third-party of pagination did you use ?  or it's write by your self ? can you give me a  link ？

Comment: Yes. From here - https://github.com/matfish2/vue-pagination-2

Comment: yes at your pagination component ，you just defined  the myCallback, and you should implement the `myCallback` in `methods` of your current vue, and the code:  `methods: {myCallback (e){this.pageNo = e; this.fetchData }, fetchData(){ ...}}` , in the fetchData method ，you  should get the new Data, you can try it

Comment: Provided my updated code as you said. Please check. Still not working. Seems like I am missing something.

Comment: `   <pagination
                    v-model="pageNo"
                    :pageLimit="4"
                   :records="records"
                    @paginate="myCallback"
                  />` please add the records props to the pagination ， it's the total count of the data

Comment: Yes I have used it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240086/discussion-between-screw-spike-and-alprazolam).

Comment: Yes I have sent my latest  codes.